# Can't vertically align divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm having a problem where I seem to be unable to get some divs to line up nicely. It doesn't really matter whether its in an accordion (like it is) or not. The accordion doesn't make a difference. Here's what it does now:

[image]

I think it's obvious that i'd like them to be vertically aligned together, at the top (as some are longer than others) If you could out, then that'd be great.

I tried to make a fiddle of it but failed miserably, so if you want to see it in action, you can find it at http://thephotoshopwirral.com/covers.php

If you need any more info, just ask. I'll do my best to help you.

Comment: Did you validate the HTML? Did you close the `label` elements?

Comment: You're nesting all the `<label>`s one inside another.

Comment: You have a html mess-up. You've failed to close some html tags.

Comment: You mean horizontally aligned, right? You want them aligned along their top. Such that the top _horizontal_ lines should be flush. Horizontally.

Comment: I said vertically because I wanted them aligned on the same vertical line, and the `vertical-align` property does that.

Comment: I suggest you to download the "firebug" plugin to firefox, and learn to use that. It is not easy at beginning, but opens a whole world.

Comment: Yeah, that property is in reference to the alignment relative to the top and bottom of the viewport - not sibling elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `<br>` tags between your labels. Remove them.

```
<label><br><label>
```

Comment: He also has them wrapped inside a main label which isn't necessary.

Comment: He also states they should be _vertically_ aligned, which would mean one after the other in a column running from top to bottom, not a row running from left to right. I think they just don't know what horizontal and vertical means, but it's a noteworthy point.

Comment: @GrantThomas `<label>` is `display: inline` by default so it should work once the OP corrects the typo.

Answer (score 1):

You're not closing the `label` elements. I suggest validating your HTML.

Also you can't put `div` elements within `label` elements.. I suggest restructuring.

Comment: Just because "it works" doesn't mean it's a misuse of HTML/structure. It's still semantically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of closing `<label>` tags, you're opening new ones:

```
<label><div class="phoneitem">
    <img src="http://www.thephotoshopwirral.com/image/phones/bold.png" width="200" height="250" alt=""/>
    <input type="radio" name="phones" value="1" id="phones_">
    Blackberry Bold         
</div><label> <!-- THIS LINE -->
```

Replace `<label>` in the specified line to `</label>`.

Comment: yeah that was just a typo. I tried various things to make it work to no avail, and when I restored it to how it was, I forgot the "/" in the closing label tag.